# Google Docs - Extend with a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-docs

I was building a container bound script for google docs, then wanted a solution that would work on all documents, not just one, so I started writing a chrome extension with content scripts that add a menu. This was really hard.

My question is, is there a good way to add a menu to ALL google docs for an account?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats the only way.
Why was it that hard with content scripts? Ive done it before.

Comment: Imitating their menus is not easy. do you know of a tutorial

Comment: You dont need to imitate them. Just use whatever classes/css it uses. The modified html can use everything theres on the html already.

Comment: Yes, But that is complicated, because you must write all of your own JavaScript, is there a way to get there js run on your menu?

Comment: No need for js. Just create the dom elements imitating the google ones and add your own events.

Comment: I have tried, there js does not work on my elements, so I have to write the click handlers and such.

Comment: Yes. You cant use their js. Only their css.